# Generate a n-color rainbow palette

Tags: colors, processing, rgb, color-palette, hsb

I'm trying to generate a rainbow with 15 different colors with ([runnable code here](http://sketchpad.cc/XEXd5II9nC)):

```java
size(360,100);
colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100); // Hue in degrees in [0, 360],
                               // saturation/brightness in [0, 100]
                               // like in Photoshop
noStroke();

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)   
{
    fill(i*24, 100, 100);      // 24*15 = 360
    rect(i*24, 0, 25, 100);
}
```

but it doesn't produce a rich 15 rainbow-color palette, instead some colors are missing (vivid yellow for example).

[image]

**Is there a well known algorithm to produce a vivid rainbow color palette?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand what's going on, try creating a program that shows a line for each value 0-360:

```java
size(360,100);
colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);                                         
noStroke();
for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)   
{
    fill(i, 100, 100);
    rect(i, 0, 1, 100);
}
```

You'll see this:

[image: color gradient]

Notice that the "vivid yellow" band is much more narrow than, for example, the green or blue bands. That's why simply sampling every X values doesn't generate a yellow color.

The yellow color is around value `60`, so you could modify your increment so it lands on 60. Drawing 12 rectangles with a width of 30 lets you land on the yellow:

```java
size(360,100);
colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);                                         
noStroke();
for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)   
{
    fill(i*30, 100, 100);
    rect(i*30, 0, 30, 100);
}
```

[image: color gradient with yellow]

Or you could come up with the values you want ahead of time and put them in an array instead of using an even distribution:

```java
int[] hueValues = {0, 15, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 225, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360};

size(360,100);
colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);                                         
noStroke();
for (int index = 0; index < hueValues.length; index++)   
{
    float rectWidth = width/hueValues.length;
    fill(hueValues[index], 100, 100);
    rect(index*rectWidth, 0, rectWidth, height);
}
```

[image: array color gradient]

Answer (score 1):

I created a function that generates N colors (rainbow) and outputs a list of strings (Hex values). This is in C# but logic can be converted. In order to understand what's going on I graphed the red, blue, and green values vs n. Doing that you'll see the three graphs each are piecewise functions with points of interest at n=0, n=1/4, n=1/2 and n=3/4.

```
    List<string> GenerateRainbowPalette(int numColors)
    {
        var toRet = new List<SKColor>();
        var n = (float)numColors;
        for(var i = 0; i< numColors; i++)
        {
            int red = 255;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;
            //red: (first quarter)
            if (i <= n / 4)
            {
                red = 255;
                green = (int)(255 / (n / 4) * i);
                blue = 0;
            }
            else if (i <= n / 2)  //2nd quarter
            {
                red = (int)((-255)/(n/4)*i + 255 * 2);
                green = 255;
                blue = 0;
            }
            else if (i <= (.75)*n)
            { // 3rd quarter
                red = 0;
                green = 255;
                blue = (int)(255 / (n / 4) * i + (-255 * 2));
            }
            else if(i > (.75)*n)
            {
                red = 0;
                green = (int)(-255 * i / (n / 4) + (255 * 4));
                blue = 255;
            }

            //generate hex string:
            var redHex = red.ToString("X2");
            var greenHex = green.ToString("X2");
            var blueHex = blue.ToString("X2");

            var color = $"#{redHex}{greenHex}{blueHex}";
        
         
            toRet.Add(color);
        }
        return toRet;
    }
```